# How to monitor google app engine from command line?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm starting to use Google App Engine and being a newcomer to much of the stuff going on here, I broke my webpage (all I see is "server error" in my web browser). I'd like to be able to see a console of some sort which is telling me what's going wrong (python syntax? file not found? something else?). Searching around a bit didn't lead me to a quick solution to this, so I came here. Any advice? Ideally, there would be some sort of tutorial/guide that would show how to do this.

Comment: if you enable debugging (debug = True for webapp2) then the error message in the browser will be much more informative

Answer (score 1):

Why from the command line? You should look in the App Engine console at https://appengine.google.com for the logs.

Answer (score 1):

Login with your account at http://appengine.google.com and select the particular application that you wish to monitor.

From the left panel, go to Main --> Logs. This should give you the details on what is going on, endpoints being accessed, any exceptions, etc. This could be the first step.

If you want to automate some of this, you will need to write endpoints that report back health of the system and then tools can be written to invoke those URLs, parse the responses and then notify folks in case of issues. But all that would be custom driven and dependent on your application alerts.

Answer (score 1):

1. I assume you are using Linux, Ubuntu/Mint If not that would be a good start
2. Debug as much as you can locally using dev_appserver.py - this will display errors on start up (in the console)
3. Add your own debug logs when needed
4. Run code snippets in the interactive console - this is really useful to test snippets of code:

   - if you are on GAE >= 1.7.6 `http://localhost:8000/console`
   - if you are on GAE < 1.7.6 `http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin/interactive/interactive`